# Typescript assign 'Object' a specific type instead of 'any'

Tags: typescript, eslint

Because of --strict_checks and typescript eslint checks, I am trying to fix some new errors in my code. Code examples below for everything I explain. Say I have an Object a, and I want to directly specify it as a map to get around some errors. I can't use the keyword "any". This is what I am trying to do:

```
isEquivalent(a: Object, b: Object): boolean {
   const aObject: {[index: string]: Object} = a;
   const bObject: {[index: string]: Object} = b;
}
```

Link to the typescript playground with the actual code snippet: [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgSQHYCsCmBjGBDAIwBtM4BfOAMyghDgHIABPVAcwFci8oB6baTPQDcAKBGM0WXIRIAKBCLhwwNAG7AAJpg1oAXAxoQY9EWQCUIzAA9IsONi4BnR3ACqMYEUcBlTFHXYpAoiPDxwACoAFqSU7Ki4wBCocNFQpMAuMBD20dgA1nAA7tEwqXClpDCF2dwcIJioMC7cpJgAjuzAqngkjXDQinChcKhGcJjgMACe-VAjRgB0cN4QADRFpNgso-CReKqkLDOOYDjAlMDY5VOncFoXqNpU0OXRg8O17PWNzagar4coHUGk04C04Kwug0wRCGn5LtdbhBKHAAPIEKQwBbvABUOMGcBxcEYYG4eDoCHRmIoeDgAFoAVRgFBHPAIBicPAsnACJtaKS0hpsUpCcSBeTEFTORQCPTGY4cEl-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)
But this throws the error:

*error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type '{ [index: string]: Object; }'.
The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
Index signature is missing in type 'Object'.*

Can anyone point me to the solution for the type to specify object as, without using 'any'? Or if this isn't possible, please let me know.

Comment: Made the changes you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

`const aObject: {[index: string]: Object} = a;` assigns `a` (of type `Object`) to `aObject` (of type `{[index: string]: Object}`, an object with string property names and `Object` property values). But `Object` is not assignment-compatible with `{[index: string]: Object}`, so TypeScript gives you that error.

If you want to force it, you can do a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```typescript
const aObj = a as {[index: string]: Object};
```

[Updated playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgSQHYCsCmBjGBDAIwBtM4BfOAMyghDgHIABPVAcwFci8oB6baTPQDcAKBGM0WXIRIAKBCLhwwNAG7AAJpg1oAXAxoQY9EWQCUIzAA9IsONi4BnR3ACqMYEUcBlTFHXYpAoiPDxwACoAFqSU7Ki4wBCocNFQpMAuMBD20dgA1nAA7tEwqXClpDCF2dwcIJioMC7cpJgAjuzAqngkjXDQinChcKhGcJjgMACe-VAjRgB0cN4QADRFpNgso-CReKqkLDOOYDjAlMDY5VOncFoXqNpU0OXRg8O17PWNzagar4coHUGk04C04Kwug0wRCGn5LtdbhBKHAAPIEKQwBbvABUOMGcBxcEYYG4eDoCHRmIoeDgAFoAVRgFBHPAIBicPAsnACJtaKS0hpsUpCcSBeTEFTORQCPTGY4cEl-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)

**But** beware that type assertions mostly disable TypeScript's type checking. The caller could pass in `{a: 42}`, which is **not** a `{[index: string]: Object}`, and TypeScript would allow it because you've said the parameter is just `Object` but then you're treating it as `{[index: string]: Object}`.

Sometimes that's appropriate, but you might consider giving the parameters the type `{[index: string]: Object}` instead of using a type assertion within the function. That way, TypeScript can ensure that only correctly-typed objects are passed in.